# Get a large int from getchar() in C?

Tags: c, input, integer, text-files, getchar

I'm reading a file with '$' seperated values like W$65345$23425 and have been using getchar() to get me the values (while n=getchar() != '$') and so on. When I get to the second value I make an integer list and fill that list with the getchar() so i'm pretty sure I have a list of 
[6,5,3,4,5]. How do I turn that into an int with value 65345?
Here is my code:

```
void read_data(char* pa,int*  pb,double*  pc){
        int n;
        pa = &n;
        n = getchar();

        int j[25];
        int m = 0;
        while ((n=getchar()) != '$'){
                j[m] = n;
                m++;
        }
        pb = &j;

        n = getchar();

        int x[25];
        m = 0;
        while ((n=getchar()) != '$'){
                x[m] = n;
                m++;
        }
        pc = &x;
        return ;
}
```

Comment: The return type of `getchar()` is `int`, not `char`. You should fix that first.

Comment: Use `strtol` to convert string to number.

Comment: `pb = &j;` sorry, but this line made me hungry.

Comment: No, please RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int read_data()
{
    int n = getchar();
    int ret = 0;
    while(n != '$')
    {
        ret = 10 * ret + n - '0';
        n = getchar();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Superfluous condition. When `n >= '0' && n <= '9'` then certainly `n != '$'` so there's no need to test for `'$'`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `getchar` returns the character read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`. This means the below statement assigns the character code (ASCII value) of the character read by `getchar` -

```
j[m] = n;
```

You can use the standard library function `strtol` to convert a string to `long int`. You have to change your `int` array to a `char` array.

```
char *endptr;  // needed by strtol

// note that the size of the array must be large enough
// to prevent buffer overflow. Also, the initializer {0}
// all elements of the array to zero - the null byte.
char j[25] = {0};

int m = 0;
while ((n = getchar()) != '$'){
    j[m] = n;
    m++;
}

// assuming the array j contains only numeric characters
// and null byte/s.
// 0 means the string will be read in base 10
int long val = strtol(j, &endptr, 0);
```